# Is there any scripts or add-ons for EEVEE tile rendering?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

As all you know EEVEE doesn't support tile rendering. When project exceeds the limit, Blender crashes instantly when I try to render the scene. I'm animating the shift x-y values of the camera for tile rendering and merging those frames with Photoshop. It's not that hard but I'ld like to know if you guys have any better ways in your mind? Some way to get a whole render image, not frames to be merged.
I already am automating the merging process on the Photoshop but a few errors appear on frame borders. Especially if the 'Bloom' option is enabled.

Sometimes I need the PNG version of a specific object so I render that object solo, import it to Photoshop and simply select the pixels to get the selection of that part. To do that the PNG version have to fit 100% with the original render and with that animated camera render it always a headache.

I thought and hope you have better idea or script/add-on to get a whole render image on EEVEE with tile size option. Using the camera as a scanner sounds like a stone age thing. Thank you all!

Comment: Can you provide a scene that crashes? Otherwise hard to test whether tiling would work at all... Have you tried rendering using the command line already to save some memory?

Comment: @brockmann Hey, thank you for that comment! Sure, here let me show you this scene here which crashes instantly if I try to render it with more than 1000x1000 resolution. I know the geometry is just too much but I need a smooth curtain on the background and I think it have to be high-poly. https://imgur.com/4NEQomx https://imgur.com/MJphgL3

Comment: @brockmann btw same for the rendering with cmd.

Comment: I mean can you share a file? Don't have to be this one, any example scene that crashes...? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I'm not able to write any code based on 2 images.